# Use WMIC to find open files of a process

Tags: windows, wmi, wmic

Is there a way do get a list of open files for a process using WMIC?

Yes, there are sysinternals like [`HANDLE.EXE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) that can do this, but you have to get a copy, but more importantly if you are scripting with it and want to distribute the script, you would have to distribute the utility too.  That may involve licensing problems.

But WMIC is pretty much already distributed.  `HANDLE.EXE` may be querying WMI information under the hood, but I don't know. Certainly the `Win32_Process` class seems involved somehow. If so, WMIC should be able to get at it too.  How?  Or is `HANDLE.EXE` accessing other things than WMI information?

Comment: It's not directly possible with `wmic`.

Comment: Even grabbing several different outputs for different classes, then letting the script cross-match things would be acceptable, if you count that as indirectly possible

Comment: There is no WMI class that can tell what file handles are open.

Comment: See this SO question's answers for some insight as to why it's not available via WMI (hint, you need kernel access to get the list): [How do I get the list of open file handles by process in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177146/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-c)